# Consolidate Duplicate amounts

Tags: c#, json.net

Suppose I have this JArray:

```
{
    "ArrayofItem":{
        "Item":[
        {
            "Amount": "1.52"
            "Date": "05/01/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "2.52"
            "Date": "05/01/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "5.62"
            "Date": "05/02/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "1.06"
            "Date": "05/02/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "6.30"
            "Date": "05/03/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "1.00"
            "Date": "05/04/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "1.55"
            "Date": "05/04/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "1.63"
            "Date": "05/05/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "1.78"
            "Date": "05/06/2015"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I consolidate the items so that all items of the same date are combined together to create a new JArray like this:

```
{
    "ArrayofItem":{
        "Item":[
        {
            "Amount": "4.04"
            "Date": "05/01/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "6.68"
            "Date": "05/02/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "6.30"
            "Date": "05/03/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "2.55"
            "Date": "05/04/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "1.63"
            "Date": "05/05/2015"
        },
        {
            "Amount": "1.78"
            "Date": "05/06/2015"
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially I need a summarized by date list of the original items. You can assume that the items are already sorted by date.

Comment: Seems like you need to deserialize into your original object structure, modify it to the new structure and reserialize it.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code as your model:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Arrayofitem ArrayofItem { get; set; }
}

public class Arrayofitem
{
    public Item[] Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

and then this code will do the work:

```
string jsonText = "your json text goes here...";    
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonText);
var itemArray = o.ArrayofItem.Item
                             .GroupBy(item => item.Date, (date, item) => 
                                    new Item 
                                    { 
                                        Date = date, 
                                        Amount = item.Sum(i => float.Parse(i.Amount)).ToString() 
                                    }).ToArray();

string serializedGroup = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Rootobject { ArrayofItem = new Arrayofitem { Item = itemArray } });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this purely with [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm), you can use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the necessary objects:

```
        var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        var query = obj.SelectTokens("ArrayofItem.Item")
            .SelectMany(t => t)
            .OfType<JObject>()
            .GroupBy(o => o["Date"], o => o["Amount"])
            .Select(g => new JObject(new JProperty("Amount", g.Sum(a => (decimal)a)), new JProperty("Date", g.Key)));
        var newObj = new JObject(new JProperty("ArrayofItem", new JObject(new JProperty("Item", new JArray(query)))));
```